# Making fast drawing canvas like Photoshop in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++, canvas

I have to write a faster canvas in wpf for my upcoming project. The canvas will be similar to adobe photoshop canvas. It should have layers and objects and also direct drawing methods.

I am thinking to write the canvas in vc++ or in c# and use it into wpf. Is it a good idea to write the canvas in any other language and use it with wpf? Or should I extend the existing canvas of wpf? If using other language, then vc++ will be better or c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use QT. :)

Comment: Do you find it easier to use VC++?

Comment: Similar to vc++, I don't have much vc++ experience :(

Comment: When it comes to graphics, canvas, animation and the like... QT comes pretty handy compared to VC++... Take a look at these examples... http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/examples-graphicsview.html

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the writeable bitmap - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

This allows direct pixel level manipulation of graphical data, basically designed for what you want to do.